# UIButton comes back as (null) in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I was having some issues with a UIbutton where its clickable on the first 2 rows. but not the 3rd, so i tried logging the button and it comes back as null when the view is first loaded.

Here is how im creating my button inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIButton *Button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(Button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSLog(@"BUTTON: %@",Button);
```

this is what i get in the log

```
 BUTTON: (null)
```

Comment: Issue Occure may be reusing the cell .

Comment: May be you have some other UI Object for same tag value ..  try by changing the tag value for that button

Comment: Do you use ARC? And is the reference to your button (the IBOutlet) declared as weak on your cells class?

Comment: If you are retrieving the button from a cell in storyboard or xib, check if you have same tag.

Comment: please provide cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this ..

```
UIButton *createbtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

createbtn.frame=CGRectMake(200, 20, 100, 30);

[createbtn setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[createbtn addTarget:self action
                        :@selector(onButtonClk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:createbtn];

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *stringIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stringIdentifier];
  if(cell==nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:stringIdentifier];
  }
 //1. create button type as custom
 UIButton *Btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 //2. set the frame for visibility
 Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,55,55)]; // change the frame where you need

 //3. add the action for button
 [Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 //4. get the current cell index
 Btn.tag = indexpath.row;

 //5. choices if you want to add image for button
 [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 //6. if you want to add title for button
 [Btn setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 //7.set font for title
 [Btn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];

 //8. set color for title
 [Btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//9. add subview to cell
 cell.contentView addSubview:Btn];

 return cell;

}
```

Button Action method

```
-(void)actionButtonPress:(UIButton*)sender
{
   //get the current index 
   NSLog(@"current index == %@", sender.tag);
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Also you can set the tag for button in cellForRowAtIndexPath below like this

```
   UIButton *Btn = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
   Btn.tag = indexpath.row;
```

Credits go to MY BELOVABLE BROTHER AnbuKarthickeyan

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all your naming convention for variable is off. You should name `Button` as `button`.

**Second**, I would advise you to create a custom cell - subclass of `UITableViewCell` and button in `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)iStyle reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)iReuseIdentifier` method.

Creating a button or changing button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is a heavy job as this method gets called for each cell drawing and re-drawing.

**Third**, implement `- (void)layoutSubviews` method in custom cell class to do any run time change in cells.